# why is @font-face not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have an extremely frustrating problem. I am trying to install a font to a website which I am building however the font does not seem to want to work. I have all of the different font formats for all the different browsers. My code is below.

A live link of the website can be found [HERE](http://www.mildenhire.com/other/index.html), however for future users I shall be removing this as soon as the question is answered

***css font***

```
<style>

@font-face {
font-family: 'myfamily';
src: url('segoeuil.eot');
src: url('segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('segoeuil.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('segoeuil.woff') format('woff'),
     url('segoeuil.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('segoeuil.svg#segoe_uilight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

html code

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide1.png);"><div style="text-align: center;">
<div>
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'">we are the blah blah blah</h1>
</div><h2>we are blah blah blah.</h2>
</div>
<div id="apDiv2"></div>
</li> 
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide2.png);"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide3.png);;"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide4.png);"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide5.png);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi again :) Did you put the font files on your server?

Comment: hahaha Hi Bojan! the answers worked on the h1 tag but not the h2 please check the updated live view, the thing is that this font is meant to be much lighter than how it is displaying on my browser. Its displaying as a bolder font than it does in word or photoshop. This web design seems like too much hard work! haha @BojanPetkovski

Comment: Don't write inline css. In the css file simply write h1, h2{ font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-weight: normal; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your css you give the font-family a name (`font-family: 'myfamily';`), then in HTML you trying to target to the font with a different name...
the correct code to make this work is:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'myfamily';
src: url('segoeuil.eot');
src: url('segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('segoeuil.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('segoeuil.woff') format('woff'),
     url('segoeuil.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('segoeuil.svg#segoe_uilight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

and then

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide1.png);"><div style="text-align: center;">
<div>
  <h1 style="font-family: 'myfamily'">we are the blah blah blah</h1>
</div><h2>we are blah blah blah.</h2>
</div>
<div id="apDiv2"></div>
</li> 
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide2.png);"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide3.png);;"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide4.png);"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide5.png);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey guys this worked on the h1 tag but not the h2 please check the updates live view, the thing is that this font is meant to be much lighter than how it is displaying on my browser. Its displaying as a bolder font than it does in word or photoshop.

Comment: In your code you specify the font-family just for the h1 tag (it is inline-styled)... if you want to set that font for other tag too you have to add other rules, i suggest you to use a separated css file though.

Comment: and for the bolder visualization... browser default css usually set heading tag (h1,h2,h3 and so on) to be with a bold font-weight. you have to reset this porperty too if you want a lighter font.
<h1 style="font:family:'myfamily'; font-weight:normal">...</h1>

Answer (score 1):

You're simply calling the wrong `font-family` name

You need to change the css to:

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
}
```

So that it matches what you have in your HTML:

**HTML**

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'">we are the blah blah blah</h1>
```

Comment: hey guys this worked on the h1 tag but not the h2 please check the updates live view, the thing is that this font is meant to be much lighter than how it is displaying on my browser. Its displaying as a bolder font than it does in word or photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You have called the font `font-family: 'myfamily';` in the CSS, but you reference it as `font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'` in the HTML.

This looks like the issue.

Comment: hey guys this worked on the h1 tag but not the h2 please check the updated live view, the thing is that this font is meant to be much lighter than how it is displaying on my browser. Its displaying as a bolder font than it does in word or photoshop

Answer (score 0):

Set font famly name same
ANd check exist in your server font

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
src: url('segoeuil.eot');
src: url('segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('segoeuil.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('segoeuil.woff') format('woff'),
     url('segoeuil.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('segoeuil.svg#segoe_uilight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
h1,h2,h3{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
}
```

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide1.png);"><div style="text-align: center;">
<div>
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'">we are the blah blah blah</h1>
</div><h2>we are blah blah blah.</h2>
</div>
<div id="apDiv2"></div>
</li> 
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide2.png);"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide3.png);;"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide4.png);"></li>
<li style="background-image: url(images/slide5.png);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey guys this worked on the h1 tag but not the h2 please check the updated live view, the thing is that this font is meant to be much lighter than how it is displaying on my browser. Its displaying as a bolder font than it does in word or photoshop

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes from the font name...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfamily';
    ...
}
```

change 'myfamily' tpo just myfamily as in...

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myfamily;
   ...
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: hey guys this worked on the h1 tag but not the h2 please check the updated live view, the thing is that this font is meant to be much lighter than how it is displaying on my browser. Its displaying as a bolder font than it does in word or photoshop.